# Query 3 meta_key and orderby

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I need to show the result of 3 queries and I made this query but I can not show the result, I throw a table that does not have the order I want. This is the query:

```
$args3 = array(
        'post_type' => $directory_url_2, // enter your custom post type
        'paged' => $paged,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
'meta_query' => array(
    'post_type' => $directory_url_2, // enter your custom post type
        'paged' => $paged,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'relation' => 'AND',
    'premium_clause' => array(
        'meta_key'     => 'premium',
        'meta_compare' => 'LIKE',
        'orderby' => array('_post_views' => 'DESC' , 'post_name' => 'ASC')
     ),
     'other_clause' => array(
      'meta_key'     => 'premium',
        'meta_compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        'orderby' => array('_post_views' => 'DESC' , 'post_name' => 'ASC')
     ),
    'orderby' => array(
      'premium_clause' => 'ASC', 
      'other_clause' => 'ASC',  
      ),
    ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

The meta_query has to be an array of array to manage the relation between the meta queried.

You can read more on the codex page about wp_query [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)

In an other side, post_type, post_status, has nothing to do on your meta_query clause, they are already in the main arguments if the query.